# How to set and iterate a variable in the same function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

This is the easiest way I could show my problem. (using PyCharm and Python 3.8):

```
ball_pos1 = [0,0]
    
def set(a):
    global ball_pos1
    ball_pos1 = [a,0]

def update(x):
    ball_pos1[0] += x

def setup (b,y):
    set(b)
    update(y)

for i in range(0,5):
    print(ball_pos1)
    setup(0,1)
```

OutPut :

```
[0, 0]
[1, 0]
[1, 0]
[1, 0]
[1, 0]
```

i want the output to be :

```
[0, 0]
[1, 0]
[2, 0]
[3, 0]
[4, 0]
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `setup(0, 1)` *always* resets (by calling `set(0)`) the position before calling `update(1)` to increment it.

Comment: You call `set(b)` from `setup()` which resets `ball_pos[0]` back to `0`.

Comment: I assume `setup` isn't useful; instead, call `set(0)` before the loop and call `update(1)` inside the loop.

Comment: Also, you'll want to learn about classes rather than simulating them (poorly) with functions and global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were setting the value of the first element of the `ball_pos1` list to 0 every time you iterated over the list, so it would be incremented to the value of 1 and then set back to 0 again when you ran over the loop, here is the working code:

```
ball_pos1 = [0,0]
    
def set(a):
        global ball_pos1
        ball_pos1 = [a,0]

def update(x):
    ball_pos1[0] += x

def setup (y):
    update(y)

for i in range(0,5):
        print(ball_pos1)
        if i != 0:
            setup(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You way over complicated it.  If you are simply worried about printing the value:

```
ball_pos = [0, 0]

for i in range(0, 5):
    print([ball_pos[0]+i, ball_pos[1]])
```

if you want to assign a new list:

```
x = [[0+i, 0] for i in range(0,5)]
```

Comment: I think he does want to update the variable, not just print incrementing numbers.

Comment: Thanks, but i am not only worried about printing, i will later need to use the variable, i just simplified everything to try and find my mistake

Comment: I added a solution that does it in one line

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your variable 'i' in the loop.

```
for i in range(0,5):
    setup(i,1)
    print(ball_pos1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ball_pos1 = [0,0]
    
def set(a):
    global ball_pos1
    ball_pos1 = [a,0]
    
def update(x):
    ball_pos1[0] += x
   

def setup (b,y):
    if ball_pos1[0] == 0:
        set(b)
        update(y)
    else:
        update(y)

for i in range(0,5):
    print(ball_pos1)
    setup(0,1)
```

The problem with your code is, it actually keep on changing the ball_pos1[0] to 0 whenever it calls set(b). We just need to call it once to get the intended result. If you have this problems you may use print().